# How to add a custom function on click in v-slide-item?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

As what we can see in here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/slide-groups/

Vuetify already provide a slide groups with default v-slot inside the v-slide-item, such as:

```
v-slot:default="{ active, toggle }"
```

then inside the v-slide-item, we can add a component, example v-card, but we need to have the default @click="toggle" such as:

```
<v-card @click="toggle"> some contents </v-card>
```

that toggle is used for the v-slot.

My issue is when I want to call my own function, I tried to create another component inside the v-card, then add @click="myFunction".

But that function is being called more than 1 time (as many times as the v-slide-item). If I have 10 items, that function is being called 10 times, although I only click once in that item.
The same thing happens when I tried adding a component on top of that v-card.

The weird thing is if I change the click function in v-card, it's only being called once. So I think I should call my function in v-card, but it's being used by toggle. Any suggestion what I can do to call my own function in that v-card?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to realised that somehow beside @click, we can also add v-on:click.

So to solve my issue, in my v-card, I have 2 on-click functions.